# I want to download file using direct link without file read

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, iis, download

I am using this code, but through this code happens read file. i want to download this file using this direct link without byte read. If there is a  another way to do this, present it. **Is there any other way  without using WebClient** and How to do without save path

> ```
>         System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
>         string url = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";
>         byte[] bytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
>         string filename = Path.GetFileName(url);
>         Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
>         Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
>         Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
>         Response.End();
> ```

Comment: Use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) instead of WebClient: _"We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class."_ - [WebClient Remarks Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

Comment: I agree HttpClient is better, especially if you can correctly use async/await, but `WebClient` literally has a `DownloadFile` method.

Comment: ^^ [WebClient.DownloadFile(string,string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netcore-3.1) _"Downloads the resource with the specified URI to a local file."_

Comment: Is there any other way  without using WebClient

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way without using WebClient

Sure.  Just get a Stream can copy it to the Http Response stream.  Something like:

```
        System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string url = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";
        Stream data = webClient.OpenRead(url);
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(url);
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        data.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.End();
```

Comment: Can download file from the direct link without reading the file

Comment: Is that a question?

Answer (score 0):

you could try blow code:

```
string k = "http://sub.domain.com/uploads/test.pdf";
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test_PDF.pdf");

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        byte[] myDataBuffer = wc.DownloadData(k);
        Response.BinaryWrite(myDataBuffer);
        Response.End();
```

[image]